# Opening anchor tag from iframe in parent frame

Tags: html

Given the following HTML, is it possible for the anchor tag in the iframe to target the parent window?

```
<div>
  <iframe src="/pageview.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

iframe (pageview.html) content :

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>
```

Comment: You can't update the contents of the `<iframe>` without JavaScript.  It also doesn't make sense for the iframe to have content

Comment: @ExplosionPills that's just an anecdotal rendering of what might load in the iframe from the src. Right now, as is usual, the anchor tag opens within the iframe when clicked. I'm just wondering if there's a way to change that behavior

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want the [`target` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a#attr-target):

```
<a href="something" target="_parent">go</a>
```

Using `_parent` will target the frame's immediate parent window.  To target the top window, use `_top`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
  <iframe src="/pageview.html">
    <a onclick="javascript:window.parent.location.href='http://www.google.com'; return false;">link</a>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Should be something like that...

Comment: You should mark as answer if this solves the problem @Wesley.

Comment: I will, there is a time delay on when you can mark an answer.

Comment: This is not a good use of JavaScript.  You are simulating built-in browser behavior that has worked since the 1990's with JavaScript.  What if the user has turned off JavaScript?  Meanwhile, you eliminate the `href` attribute, which has implications for CSS, keyboard navigation, accessibility, and SEO.  And, just to nit-pick, you should not use the `javascript:` prefix in an `onclick` attribute.  Use `target="_parent"` instead.  It is cross-browser, and semantically correct.  This is exactly what the `target` attribute is for.

Comment: fair enough....I was kind of assuming this was answering more of a canonical example for someone who was eventually going to do it in JQuery programatically. I'm upvoting your ans