# Anchor link inside iframe resizer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm using [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) in my application and it works fine but I have problem with anchor links inside iframe, they doesn't work.

For example I have link `<a href="#page1"></a>` and I tried to put full url `<a href="http:///mydomain.com/page1"></a>` also tried to use target attribute. I also find something like this `<a target="_parent" href="http://parenturl.com/#my-id">jump link</a>`, I sow this solution but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: you want it to navigate to somewhere inside your iframe or to somewhere in the parent page?

Answer (score 0):

you may find your answer from below link

[Opening anchor tag from iframe in parent frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947986/opening-anchor-tag-from-iframe-in-parent-frame)

open this link and read second answer given by gilly3.

i hope this will help you to solve your problem

Comment: Thank you. I'v tried with this, doesn't help me. :(

Comment: if possible than share jsfiddle link with your code

Comment: I have found solution. :( Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

I have accidentally got his idea and it works for me. :)

I have used this

```
<a href="#mylink" onclick="location;location.href='#mylink'">
```

Also I found this solution for iframe-resizer, it have property enableInPageLinks and default is false, just need to change this to true. Also be careful to have newest version of iframe-resizer.